# What is the origin and meaning of the prayer “Koh Kaili” said before Musaf on Chagim?

Tags: song-poetry, torah-service, nuschaot, musaf

The prayer [“Koh Kaili”](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2894) is said by some before the “Ashrei” before Musaf on Sholosh Regolim.

1)  What is the origin and meaning of the prayer?

2)  In the “chorus” what are the “miluim”? Are they the korbonos for the inauguration of the mishkon?

3)  The referenced text says וְתוֹדָה and not ולַתוֹדָה then וְלָעוֹלָה. וְלַמִּנְחָה Why is the Todah different?

Answer (score 2):

I have been asking myself the same question.  A neighbor in shul said that it his Machzor it refers the reader to the footnotes of Sefer Haminhagim by R’ Issac Tirnauer (14th century).  See:

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49362&st=&pgnum=30&hilite=

footnote לד.

Of course the footnotes were written much later.

Comment: Richie, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this source! You could make your answer more valuable by [edit]ing in a summary of what the source says. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: The source says that we do not say "Koh Kaili" when we say Yizkor.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I should have done more research before posting the question. Here is a little contribution to answer questions 1 and 2.

In the Koren Sacks siddur, he says that the prayer first appeared in siddur “Shaar Hashamayim" of R. Isaiah Horowitz but I can’t find it [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42822&st=&pgnum=481).

The Artscroll siddur comments, amongst other things, on the difficult order of the korbonos. Perhaps the Todoh comes first as thanksgiving for returning to EI, the Oloh represents Israel’s longing for elevation and comes before atonement offerings.  The Miluim are mentioned last because they will be brought only once at the dedication of the third Beis Hamikdosh bimhairo beyomeinu.